# SharePoint App asking for credentials for each domain of app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, dns

I have main SharePoint site on domain contoso.com and app is on contosoapps.com

I created all the required entries in DNS. like Host A and CNAME for wildcard.

Now both are working fine but when i open the app, it asking for credentials.

Is there any way we can skip that popup of credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, i see three solutions:

1. Users have to add your AppDomain to the InternetExplorer Zone "Local Intranet" on the client manually.

[image: IE Zones]

2. Implement [ADFS + WebApplicationProxy](http://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy) with Kerberos-Authentication on [Windows Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765473(v=ws.11).aspx). If configured correctly, WAP will use User's SharePoint authentication and pass it through to your AppDomain.
3. Instead of OnPremises WAP you can publish SharePoint via [Azure AD ApplicationProxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-enable-remote-access-sharepoint). It's super-easy to implement, but you need an [Azure AD Basic License](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) for each user.

Comment: how we do in client machine? is there any proper solution? @Mheld

Comment: This is normally deployed to the whole organization with Group Policies. There are two ways to build an according GPO, both are described here: https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/group-policy-internet-explorer-security-zones.html. I highly prefer the second way, as it doesn't break existing settings and still allows users to add sites on their own.

Comment: For testing you can add the site on one client manually as you can see in my screenshot.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct but our site users are not in our domain.

Comment: Updated answer above

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MHeld. Cant we do without azure & ADFS? I dont want single sign on.  When we open SharePoint site, it will ask for login and when i open app, it will again ask for login. i just want to remove that login in app.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but SharePoint won't help you out-of-the-box with that problem. Credential handling between SharePoint-Domain and App-Domain must be done with an external Tool. ADFS+WAP and AzureADProxy are my favorites. I have seen customers implementing this with Citrix Netscaler and F5 BigIP, too. But that's much more effort&money.

Comment: By the way: My suggested solutions offer a really great login-experience with a nice form instead of the ugly windows-logon-window. And they increase security-level drastic, as they perform user-preauthentication & reverse-proxying.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers. If we use same domain for both sharepoint and app, it will work, right.

Comment: If you use sharepoint.contoso.com for SharePoint, you can configure *.apps.contoso.com for apps. This is not security best-practise from Microsoft, but it works. It's not much work to reconfigure and i've documented the tasks already here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222047/sharepoint-add-in-modify-app-domain-name/223680#223680. To be honest: I am not sure if InternetExplorer will send Credentials to a different subdomain. I've never tested this scenario. My assumption: It will not work and you still have to work with external tools.